# Know the nature of a URL before GETting it

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

Is it possible to know the nature of a URL before `GET`ting it ?

I have one URL in particular that ends with m3u but is not a simple file I can download. This is actually a radio stream. As I expect a (finite) file, the `GET` method never ends. The timeout options does not works in this case (normal).

```
const options = {timeout: 5000};
return HTTP.call('GET', "http://av.rasset.ie/av/live/radio/junior.m3u", options);
```

The safe solution should be to ask for the type of the response before actually getting the file.
How can I do that?

Thanks,
Mickael.

Comment: I guess you can run a `HEAD` request first (instead of `GET`) and verify the headers. Then after making `GET` you will know how to react.

Comment: For this particular URL, when running a HEAD, I get a HTTP Parse Error. That is strange because other sites can run this radio station just fine. Anyway, thanks for this tip. I think it is a fine solution.

Comment: Yes, they probably do not support `HEAD` method. May I add the answer myself?

Comment: Yes, of course, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can run a `HEAD` request first (instead of `GET`) and verify the headers. Then after making `GET` you will know how to react.

Unfortunately in this particular case `HEAD` works for the first request (which returns a redirect):

```
 curl -v -X HEAD http://icecast1.rte.ie/junior               http://av.rasset.ie/av/live/radio/junior.m3u
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the 
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
*   Trying 104.16.107.29...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to av.rasset.ie (104.16.107.29) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /av/live/radio/junior.m3u HTTP/1.1
> Host: av.rasset.ie
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 11:07:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d89353ae357a0452208835b3092f0fbee1510571253; expires=Tue, 13-Nov-18 11:07:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.rasset.ie; HttpOnly
< Location: http://icecast1.rte.ie/junior
< X-Server-Name: djd
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< X-Varnish: 2802121867
< X-Served-By: MISS: mt-www2.rte.ie
< CF-Cache-Status: MISS
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 3bd1449d2764410c-HAM
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
^C
```

But fails for second (probably `HEAD` is not supported, should return `405`):

```
 curl -v -X HEAD http://icecast1.rte.ie/junior               
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the 
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
*   Trying 89.207.56.171...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to icecast1.rte.ie (89.207.56.171) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /junior HTTP/1.1
> Host: icecast1.rte.ie
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
< Server: Icecast 2.4.2
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 11:07:42 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< 
<html><head><title>Error 400</title></head><body><b>400 - unknown request</b></body></html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Thanks Opal for making tests !

Answer (score 0):

Even if in this particular case, running HEAD runs into an HTTP Parse Error, while I know the stream is OK (if someone can still explains me why, I would be grateful), I think Opal gave the general solution:

> You can run a HEAD request first